# Why are Matlab anonymous functions called anonymous?

Tags: matlab

Here is an example for defining and using anonymous function in Matlab

```
data = 1:10;            %# A vector of data
f = @(x) x.^2;          %# An anonymous function
squaredData = f(data);  %# Invoke the anonymous function
```

The anonymous function does have a name `f`. So why is it called anonymous?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anonymous function is the expression `@(x) x.^2`.  This expression is a function which is unnamed and hence it's anonymous.  The value `f` eventually contains the expression though.  But the feature itself is usable without a name

Comment: +1. Thanks! How is it like to be defined and used without the name `f`?

Comment: @Ethan you could store them in an array `A = {@(x)x.^2, @(y)y+10, @(x,y)x.^2+y+10}`.  Source http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html

Comment: @Ethan: you could do something like `feval(@(x)(x.^2), someX)` or in a less contrived way: `fzero(@(x)(a*x.^2 + b*x + c), x0)` or something similar. As JaredPar said: the function itself has no name, but it is stored in a (named) variable. Your example cannot be used without a name, because it is a somehow ambiguous contruct: `f(x)` could either mean call function `f` with argument `x` or get the `x`th element(s) of the array `f`. When `f` happens to be a function, however, the first one is used.

Comment: @EgonGeerardyn: Thanks! Why is "Your example cannot be used without a name"? In my code, I don't use `f` for other purpose such as as an array.

Comment: @Ethan: Well, you pass your squaring function around by its  ''name'' `f`. So the construct `f(x)` is a function call for a function named `f` (or indexing into an array `f`). You could say, from a practical point of view, you paradoxically created the anonymous function named `f`. Because your function needs a ''name'' to be used in the construct `f(x)`, which is a shorthand for `feval(f, x)` in your case (and that construct can be used with an anonymous function without a ''name'', as I showed).

Comment: I do have to apologize for an error in my first comment: the ambiguity `f(x)` for both function calls and array indexing is not the reason you can't use an anonymous function (without assigning it a variable name). The real reason is that you can't compose the creation of a function handle (i.e. `@(x)(x.^2)`) and function evaluation by means of an `f(x)` construct. So `@(x)(x.^2)(someX)` is not allowed in MATLAB code. And this stands to reason, as you could replace it by `someX.^2` which is far simpler.

Answer (score 1):

No, the anonymous function does not have a name.

There is a handle to it stored in a variable named `f`.  A handle is not a function, although it can be used to call the function.